# Dehumidifier Placement for Best Moisture Reduction: Source vs Symptom Area

Tags: dehumidifier

Concerning the most effective moisture reduction, is it better to place a dehumidifier directly next to the source of the moisture (kitchen stove, shower) or directly next to the symptom area where it ultimately builds up (window), or maybe it's neither and should be placed right in the center of the entire living area, or maybe it doesn't matter at all where it's placed?

Comment: Noise is main problem.

Comment: @user263983 Assuming noise doesn't matter, then what's the most optimal placement for *effective moisture reduction*?

Comment: Dehumidifier has a fan, air is circulating. So some open space, not close to walls or another obstructions.

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter where you place the dehumidifier since humidity and the dryer air will migrate all over the house and equalize  Placing a humidifier in one room will eventually dry out the whole house. There may be a slight gain in dehumidifing a particular area where the unit sits but the air in the house will all equalize due to normal movement of the occupants and other conditions.